# ¿En cual carpeta debo hacer GIT PULL para importar proyecto Django de Github?

Tags: django, git, github, vps, digitalocean

Estoy tratando de desplegar proyecto de Django que actualmente lo tengo en Github y en Local. Me falta subirlo al servidor VPS desde Github. He configurado un VPS en DigitalOcean con las herramientas necesarias para Django.
Veo que están los siguiente archivos instalador(por defecto).
¿En qué ruta debería hacer GIT PULL para importar el proyecto de GITHUB al VPS?
¿Qué sucede con los archivos que existen con setting.py? ¿Se sobreescribirán?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: deberias hacer `git clone` no?

Comment: ¿En cual directorio de los 3 debería clonarlo?

Comment: Entiendo que en 2a, el clone debería crear la 3a